# Do we need the "cite" link below every post?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, citation

Since September 11, the "cite" option for posts on main has been promoted from being inside "share" to directly below the post, cf. [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/123/can-we-make-the-cite-link-bigger/2436).

Now, since the argument for requesting its promotion was that "MathOverflow is widely cited in the literature" and "the cite link is very important to [MathOverflow]", I figured it was reasonable to discuss the desirability of the current position of "cite" on Maths.SE.

For, if we find that hardly anybody ever uses it, clarity of the user interface may be preferred over the visibility of a rarely-used option.

So, does that "cite" link serve any purpose to you, or would you prefer to move it back to its original position?

Comment: I think even on MO it is fair to say "hardly anybody ever uses it." In my mind, its purpose is rather to *promote* citations (as opposed to actually helping create them).

Comment: While I can't quite speak for the author, http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03533 seems like a place where the "cite" button could have been helpful.

Comment: I just use uBlock to remove the cite button. A userscript or a personal CSS file could probably do the same.

Comment: Does that extra link really bother people? I like having it available, but I can use it wherever it is. However, its greater visibility *does* make it more tempting to use for those who might not otherwise cite properly.

Comment: @robjohn I think I'm a crotchety old person that can't get used to change :p More seriously I don't see myself using that feature as often as `edit`, `close` or `flag`, the button doesn't deserve being at that position. And the bibtex file produced is subpar anyway (try putting it through biblatex to see what I mean, it's even bugged if the title contains `<`or `>`), so I would probably just take the 20s needed to create the entry myself. I wouldn't care if the change hadn't shifted all the other buttons, which is annoying.

Comment: To give an example, the title `Is a differentiable function $g(x)$ a strictly increasing function iff $g'(x)>0$?` (a random question on the front page) became `TITLE = {Is a differentiable function $g(x)$ a strictly increasing function iff $g&#39;(x)&gt;0$?},`... Which is obviously not valid... [Here is the result when that issue is corrected -- pretty isn't it?](https://i.imgur.com/aiivEnA.png) It also does nothing for capital letters, and doesn't enclose math markup in braces. I don't want to sound mean, but they didn't think this through at all and just slapped a half-baked feature on.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: that looks like something to put in a bug report, not to tuck back into the "share" link to insure it doesn't get fixed. It could be that the "cite" code was written before MathJax was even around, but certainly it is now an issue on sites that use MathJax.

Comment: [It is well-known](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1002/dont-html-encode-quotes-when-creating-suggested-bibtex-entries) that the bibtex entry is pretty broken in several ways. [Some workarounds](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1631/formatting-a-citation-to-a-mathoverflow-answer/1655#1655) are described too.

Comment: @robjohn As I said, I don't see myself using that feature much if at all, so I'm not going to bother reporting the bug. I'm just saying that the care that went into creating the feature and the haste the devs have shown in fixing its bugs (the bug report quid linked is from two years ago!) should be considered when deciding if we want to prominently feature a "cite" button under every question. The whole thing looks like it was created by someone who hardly knows anything about LaTeX.

Comment: The extra link does bother me -- there's no end to the times the last week I've pressed "cite" instead of "edit" due to muscle memory (i.e. second link from the left to edit a post).

Comment: I like the cite button, but could we have more Example citations in special , how do we like to have math stackexhange links in wikipedia?

Comment: @robjohn The place where the *cite* button is at belongs to *edit*. It's a disgusting attempt at forcing people to use the feature. As bad as Skype's "Search with bing" replacement of "copy".

Comment: Yes, I've clicked "cite" so many times since it moved. If it was all the way to the right, I wouldn't mind. Don't put something that is rarely used at the front of your interface - even if people used cite were used *as often as feasibly possible* it would still be rare. @robjohn

Comment: @GitGud: that is a good point. I have no problem with moving it further to the right, essentially appending it to the existing links.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: indeed, as I replied to Git Gud, I would not mind it being moved to the end of the list of links. Since this is not a concern mentioned in the question, it is not something that my previous answer and comments dealt with.

Comment: I'd actually love it removed (maybe add it into the share box?) as I keep going to click edit....

Comment: @GitGud just to be clear, it was asked for on MO and SE did it with some hesitation, and in doing so also distributed over a few other sites. If it was an attempt, then at least it did not come from SE.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews by that logic "share" should not come first either?

Comment: Sure, but there is a site objective served by calling attention to the "share" feature - StackExchange gets money every time somebody visits. A citation is unlikely to boost traffic remotely measurably.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Who gives Stack Exchange (now Stack Overflow, Inc.) money every time somebody visits this site? And what for?

Comment: Are you unaware this is an advertiser-supported site? Visits are important for revenue. How do you think they get the money to run this site? I don't see ads on Meta, but math.stackexchange.com has them. @NormalHuman

Comment: @NormalHuman I assume advertisers do, in exchange for the fact that SO displays their ads to visitors. I know it's not literally "every time", and some users use ad blockers, but still, SO isn't a charity and they have a monetary incentive in getting more people to visit the site.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can you show me an example of a commercial ad on this site? The only ones I see are those the community itself proposed  here on Meta, without anyone paying anything.

Comment: Also. the more external links, the higher the page rank on Google, which is a key goal for any information site, whether it is commercial or not. @NormalHuman

Comment: I don't doubt the importance of Google rank for any website of any nature. It's the "ad-supported" and "gets money ... somebody visits" that I object to.

Comment: @NormalHuman It's more common on StackOverflow, where I see on the front page an ad for Windows Cloud something something. Not sure if Math.SE has or ever had ads. I sort of assumed the change was site-wide.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Okay, then for the reference: Math.SE has never carried commercial ads, and [there are no plans](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263458) to add them in foreseeable future.

Comment: @NormalHuman I don't want to get into a protracted argument about this (as I said I don't think "give money every time they visit the site" is literally true), but math.SE is part of a larger network, and the idea is presumably that every visit here is potentially a new user for the whole network, in particular the sites that carry ads. As I said, SO isn't a charity, and hosting all this can't be cheap. As far as I'm aware, ads and the "careers" thing are the two ways they make money (there may be other things I don't know about).

Comment: I suppose we can all agree that it is in the best interest of the site to have traffic. However, as the situation is not as simple as @ThomasAndrews proposed it to be, first not all traffic is the same,  and second traffic it not everything, as one of the site's (and sites' in the network more generally) assets is the idea that the content is in some sense of high quality. Thus, one citation in a scholarly journal that might attract the attention of a few additional experts and can also be used to underline the crediblity of the site might be worth more than 10k views via a popular share.

Comment: Again I do not say that this "cite" link is super-useful but the argument presented for the relative merits of "share" strike me as not to the point.

Comment: Sure, but who out there is  linking to bad posts? @quid

Comment: I never said it shouldn't exist, only that its placement was poor (particularly because it causes errors for long-time users, and because it is very prominent for a rarely-used feature.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I suppose it depends on what one considers as a good or bad post. But on the extreme end  I have a dim recollection that a busted attempt to cheat at homework got "shared" and became quite popular. I'd be pretty sure that "funny" or "curious" things do get share quite a bit.   Looking on what gave users a [publicist badge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist) it seems like  a mixed bag.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews on your second comment, look, had they asked me I would not have done it the way they did. But if one  exposes it there, I think it makes also some sense to have it *next to share* and not someplace else.

Comment: I don't use that button and probably never will since, almost by definition, research-level mathematics is done on MO and much more rarely on MSE. I would also frown with suspicion towards any article citing MSE. Most references to MSE are probably in the online world, where URLs replace classical citations. I support removing this button. But what good is such a discussion without a poll?

Answer (score 20):

I am a big fan of the cite button, because it reminds people that they are supposed to cite things they learned here on math.SE. Citations are the currency of academia -- if I write a good answer here, I want to be able to say five years later that this answer was cited so many times in so many papers. Indeed, I get a little annoyed when I see papers that use ideas they learned on MO or math.SE and don't cite them. I know that math.SE is more oriented towards students than research, but it is also important to teach students that they need to cite where they learned things! If you are allowing your students to use math.SE as a reference, then you should be requiring that they cite it just like any other source they use, and the cite button reminds them of this.

It seems that people are complaining because they have trained their muscle memory on other SE sites, or on this site before the button was there. The easy solution to this is to move the cite button to the far right.

I support moving the cite button to the far right, but keeping it visible on the main post.

Comment: "The easy solution to this is to move the cite button to the far right. " The easier solution seems to be  for those  few that really care to *just do it* on their end. (This aside, good post.)

Comment: I understand that *far right* means near the poster's name, not anywhere close to *flag*, right?

Answer (score 0):

There has been some discussion in the comments, and the most popular views are:

1. Move "cite" back into "share" or elsewhere out of view.
2. Move "cite" to behind "flag".
3. Keep "cite" where it is now.

I think 2. is closest to a compromise so I figure we can test that. Hopefully this is technically feasible.

If it doesn't work, 1. can be considered.

Comment: I think 2 is a good option.

Comment: If we wait for a while and then do 2. it will be hilarious because then some can again complain they click "flag" and "close" instead of "edit." The point of that comment is that pretty soon most will have adapted and that's that. Moving things around will just annoy more people. Also I am not really sure the "left to right" is the most apt criterion to decide where the more or less frequently used buttons should be. Especially, the last spot of a the list seems also a privileged position; mostly i for one have the cursor rather in the center or right, so it is closest and easy to aim at.

Comment: @quid One difference is that the cite button is not present on meta, or other SE sites (except MO). I agree though that left-to-right isn't really the order of important-to-less-important (I use edit, flag and close at least an order of magnitude more than share, personally).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi that's a valid point. But then we have "share|edit|close|flag" on questions, and  "share|edit|flag" on answers (or if one does not have close-privilege) while based on this reasoning of uniformity it should  better be "share|edit|flag|close." Maybe it should be like this. But it is not, and no-one seems to have problems with this. Don't get me wrong I am not a huge fan of that cite button either, and maybe it should be placed elsewhere. But I still think moving it around now is not useful and those that really want should do it on their end (as you did, IIRC).

Comment: @quid Well, even if nothing changes now, I think it's important that we as a community speak up about not liking unannounced alterations of UX. Tim Post said [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20047/updates-to-the-site#comment76181_20047) as a reply to [Asaf's comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20047/updates-to-the-site#comment76180_20047) but apparently the SE team still does as pleases them without informing us.

Comment: @Lord_Farin not quite, on MO the general site update was announced by SE. I do not think it is reasonable to have each and every *small* change announced and discussed at length. Right, they could have made a post what this is about, but I do not consider it as that relevant either.

Comment: My preference is for (1), but (2) would be a significant improvement over the present setup.